# How to get index of all specified columns from csv file depending upon the name of the columns using python

Tags: python, csv

I have some few csv files... which looks something like this...

```
id,exam1,exam1,exam1,exam2,exam2,exam2,exam3,exam3,exam3....
lv-1,sub1,sub2,sub3,sub1,sub2,sub3,sub1,sub2,sub3....
```

in the next line Here I have data.... id number and respective marks...

The problem is when I use python and try to get the index value of the column I get only the index of the first occurrence of column name.

example... Here is my python code.

```py
    import csv
    file = [location of the file]
    
    data = csv.reader(open(file,'r'),delimiter=',')
    header = next(data) 
    header = next(data)

    i = header.index("sub2")
    j = header.index("sub3")
    
    print(i,j)
```

The output gives - 2,3
But I want index numbers of other sub2 and sub3 also.

I thought to iterate through the 2nd row but no idea how to accomplish it and get the index value.

if anyone can help me please tell me how to do it with python code ?

<------------------------------------------------------SOLUTION-------------------------------------------------->

```py
    import csv

    def get_index(row_line):
        j = 0
        flag = 0
        while flag!=-1:
            item = row_line[j]
            if (item == 'sub2' or item == 'sub3'):
                indexes.append(j)
            j = j+1
            if(j >= len(row_line)):
                flag = -1
        return indexes

    s_file = input_file.csv

    data = csv.reader(open(s_file,'r'),delimiter=',')
    header = next(data) # returns the headers or `None` if the input is empty
    header = next(data) # As I have sub2,sub3 in the second row so moving to 2nd row

    with open(s_file, 'r') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)

        indexes = get_index(header)
        print(indexes) #Here you get the index values of all sub2 and sub3...
    
    # After you get the index you can carry-on with other editing on the csv file
```

<------------------------------------------------------SOLUTION-------------------------------------------------->

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure exactly what you are asking for, but I will do my best to help. Without your code or files, I'm not sure how much I can help you in terms of physically writing code, but I can definitely make some suggestions on how to get started.

Since you are parsing .csv files, I think using the python csv module will be helpful for you. This [page](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/141) contains information on how to parse csv files using python, and the module is fairly straightforward to use. If you have headers in your files above each section (exam, subject, etc. It also explains how you can utilize those to parse. Otherwise, you will need to choose a delimitor (such as a comma), to piece out the contents and sort them as desired.

Additionally, [this should also give you insight into your goal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86235/parsing-a-big-text-file-extract-data-store-it-in-a-csv-file). The poster of this code review submission seems to have the same goal in mind as what you are going for, and you may find their approach helpful to you. Good luck, and let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me. I have edited the question in more simple way. To make sure people can help me in building blocks way

Comment: Of course! In terms of the next question you asked- I believe creating a for loop might help? Like, for (each row in the file), i = header.index("sub2")
j = header.index("sub3")

print(i,j)